Cannot login on Microsoft Graph API Explorer using my Azure-AD-B2C tenant
good day. I am testing the creation and listing of users for a tenant that I created on my Azure subscription (it is worth mentioning that my subscription comes from my organization's Visual Studio subscription) and there I created an Azure AD B2C. I want to test it initially with Graph Explorer to see if all the permissions I require are granted. But when I try to log in I put the options for the tenant where I want to enter and the user account and password. But it does not log in and does not show me anything about what could have happened.
The user I'm trying to log in with has the tenant's global administrator role assigned.
In the tenant I registered the application and in the API permissions section I already granted consent.
I hope you can help me
I have tried logging into Microsoft Graph API Explorer in my organization's tenant and curiously I can enter and consume the APIs to obtain all the users. This is why I am beginning to suspect that possibly my tenant that I am testing is a third level, so to speak: Organization Tenant - Tenant created from my Visaul Studio subscription - Tenant to test. This is the source of the problem.

Do you want to list the users, to whom you assigned Global Administrator role from your Azure AD B2C tenant with the help of Microsoft Graph Explorer or using Rest API?

Is this below solution works for you?


To list the users in Azure AD B2C Tenant using Microsoft Graph Explorer

Sign-in to Azure AD B2C Tenant credentials on Microsoft Graph Explorer
Ensure your domain name ends with your B2C domain name.

Check the user details with below query:
GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

Grant User.Read.All Admin Consent from Modify Permission tab:**

Use below query to list the users:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

